# R How can I replace values with values of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a huge dataframe *df* containing Numbers in the column "a" I also have a dataFrame *name* that contains the names corresponding to these numbers.

```
df:                          
 a   b     c                   name:
 1   val1  val2                  1  cat
 1   val1  val2                  2  dog
 2   val1  val2                  3  rabbit
 3   val1  val2
 3   val1  val2
 3   val1  val2
```

Now I want to replace the numbers with the names. The new dataFrame should look like this:

```
df:                                      
   a        b     c      
   cat      val1  val2                  
   cat      val1  val2                  
   dog      val1  val2                  
   rabbit   val1  val2
   rabbit   val1  val2
   rabbit   val1  val2
```

I realized this like that. It works but I am not content, because I hardCode the names ...

```
  df$a<-replace(df$a, df$a==1, "cat" )
  df$a<-replace(df$a, df$a==2, "dog" )
  df$a<-replace(df$a, df$a==3, "rabbit" )
```

How can I get the new values out of my dataframe name ?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a hint : You can look at some join fonctions. in `dplyr` or ``data.table` for example.

Comment: df$a <- factor(df$a, levels = names[, 1], labels = names[, 2])

Comment: Thank you very much that helped :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,3,3,3), b = rep('val1', 6), c = rep('val2', 6))
df

#   a    b    c
# 1 1 val1 val2
# 2 1 val1 val2
# 3 2 val1 val2
# 4 3 val1 val2
# 5 3 val1 val2
# 6 3 val1 val2
```

using `dplyr`'s `recode()`, you can achieve this:

```
df %>% mutate(a = recode(a, '1' = 'cat', '2' = 'dog', '3' = 'rabbit'))

#        a    b    c
# 1    cat val1 val2
# 2    cat val1 val2
# 3    dog val1 val2
# 4 rabbit val1 val2
# 5 rabbit val1 val2
# 6 rabbit val1 val2
```

Comment: The difficulty with this solution is that the replacements must be manually typed '1' = 'cat' etc. Would it be possible to have two lists, one indicating what is to be replaced, and the second indicating it is to be replaced by what?

Answer (score 2):

data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,3,3,3), b = rep('val1', 6), c = rep('val2', 6))
```

replace values with characters:

```
df$a = c('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit')[ match(df$a, sort(unique(df$a))) ]
```

output

```
df
#       a    b    c
#1    cat val1 val2
#2    cat val1 val2
#3    dog val1 val2
#4 rabbit val1 val2
#5 rabbit val1 val2
#6 rabbit val1 val2
```

Comment: This solution implicity assumes that 'cat' is to be replaced by the smallest (once sorted) value of df$a. Woudl it be possible to have pairs, e.g., c(1, 'cat') which indicates what value is to be replaced with what value?

Comment: For that case you will have to merge the data by index as is done in the solution of @manotheshark And if your dataset is big then replace the data.frame with data.table and then perform merging

Answer (score 2):

This is merging the two data.frames.  This does not require hard coding any values, but only adding new values to the data.frames

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,3,3,3), b = "val1", c = "val2")
df.name <- data.frame(a = 1:3, name=c("cat", "dog", "rabbit"))

df1 <- merge(df, df.name, by = "a")  # merge two data.frames by `a`
```

Some cleanup is required if you want the name to be stored in column `a`

```
df1$a <- df1$name
df1$name <- NULL

       a    b    c
1    cat val1 val2
2    cat val1 val2
3    dog val1 val2
4 rabbit val1 val2
5 rabbit val1 val2
6 rabbit val1 val2
```