# Replace character value using another dataframe with multiple matching

Tags: r, dataframe, join, replace, stringr

```
test.vector <- c("jdoe","John Doe","jodoe","Sarah Scarlet","sscarlet","scarlet")
test.df <- data.frame("Full.Name" = c("John Doe","Sarah Scarlet"),
                      "alias1" = c("jdoe","sscarlet"),
                      "alias2" = c("jodoe","scarlet"))
want.vector <- c("John Doe","John Doe","John Doe","Sarah Scarlet","Sarah Scarlet","Sarah Scarlet")

> test.vector
[1] "jdoe"          "John Doe"      "jodoe"         "Sarah Scarlet" "sscarlet"      "scarlet" 

> test.df
      Full.Name   alias1  alias2
1      John Doe     jdoe   jodoe
2 Sarah Scarlet sscarlet scarlet     

> want.vector
[1] "John Doe"      "John Doe"      "John Doe"      "Sarah Scarlet" "Sarah Scarlet" "Sarah Scarlet"
```

All the search results like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121441/r-how-can-i-replace-values-with-values-of-another-dataframe) have exactly one matching, and `merge()` or `join()` is used.
However, in this case, there are multiple possibilities, and I am not sure how I can approach this.
Few things I tried were (with butchered syntax):

1. `str_replace(test.vector,test.df[,-1],test.df[.1])`
2. `recode(test.vector,test.df)`
3. join with `by = c(test.df[,-1], test.vector)` after changing test.vector into df

One thing to note is that the actual `test.df` I have for the project has multiple columns that are quite sparse (since each alias relates to a specific location/position). Not sure if it will cause significant difference with the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of same `dim`ensions as your data frame and let the first column recycle, then loop over the test vector to subset the array by the data frame in an `sapply`.

```
test.a <- array(test.df[, 1], dim=dim(test.df))
sapply(test.vector, function(x) test.a[x == test.df], USE.NAMES=F)
# [1] "John Doe"      "John Doe"      "John Doe"      "Sarah Scarlet" "Sarah Scarlet"
# [6] "Sarah Scarlet"
```